# Нужна ли запятая перед "и" или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед "и" в данном случае? "Будем надеяться" - это общая вводная конструкция.

> Будем надеяться, повезёт(,) и разбогатею.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь лучше поставить тире: ***Будем надеяться, повезёт** – **и разбогатею**.*

**Пояснение**

Вводная конструкция действительно кажется **общей**, но без паузы и знака предложение читается **невыразительно**.

Также два односоставных предложения в ССП **разноструктурные** и по семантике не выглядят **однородными** (а это является дополнительным условием для их объединения и отсутствия запятой).

Но еще одна запятая в таком коротком предложении приведет к **непониманию структуры** предложения, поэтому ставим **интонационное тире**. Это дополнительный знак в ССП.

[§ 32. Тире в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135)

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что она общая для этих частей. Здесь явно имеется значение следствия. Он надеется, что сначала повезет, и тогда  (после того как ему повезет) он разбогатеет, основная часть не выражает одинаковых отношений. Вы сами чувствуете, что здесь нужен знак, значит отношения не тождественны.

Comment: Думаю, что по семантике значение  следствия в этом сообщении  далеко не явное. Например, в таком предложении это уже однородные изъяснительные придаточные (в этом случае нет значения следствия): *Он надеется, что ему повезет и (что) он разбогатеет.*

Comment: @МиМопи Здесь другие отношения (следствия нет): *Будем надеяться, повезёт, то есть что разбогатею.* В разговорной речи такое часто выражается с "и". Но, увы, она по смыслу общая даже при вашей трактовке (она маловероятна): *Будем надеяться, что повезёт и что потом разбогатею.* Если поставить запятую, то получится, что он разбогатеет при любом раскладе, так как это уже не относится к надеждам.